# how to embed codes on html pages

Tags: javascript, code-snippets

I'm on windows and I want to create a web-based code snippet tool for my own consumption. Because every awesome app seems to exist only on mac. Snippley is ok, but it doesn't have a search functionality.
Is there a javascript library or a jquery plugin that allows me to present code snippets in a nice way? Something like the one in Nettuts:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most beautiful and most used i guess is the Google code Prettify.
It's a css library for doing exactly this screenshot you paste.

http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

you can use it with Twitter Bootstrap Css library too with Google Code Prettify: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Check the page source of Twitter Bootstrap and you gonna see that you need only something like this:

```
<link href="assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or you can choose between 16 free javascript code protiffiers here: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/16-free-javascript-code-syntax-highlighters-for-better-programming/

and that's it!

Comment: check the answer again. I've edited it. is that what you need?

Comment: First, I don't need anything because I didn't ask the question ;). Second, what I meant was that Google's prettify is not only CSS, it also contains JavaScript.  You also have to include the JavaScript file, not only the CSS file to make it work. You stated that it is a CSS library which I'd say is not correct.